# assign value to object rather than its attribute in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.x = None

obj = Foo()
```

Is there any way when any value is assigned to object like

```
obj = 25
```

any method(or magic method) from Foo class is called with value 25 as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload the `=` operator since it's not an operation that is done on the object itself, but it's used to change the data that the variable is referencing.

Here is a list of operators that you can overload:
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php